# Using destructuring/spreading to copy object with renamed properties in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, spread-syntax

I need a function that maps object from one type to another:

I have an object like this:

```
interface IEntityPerson {
  person_id: number
  name: string
  age: number
  address: IAddress
}

const orig: IEntityPerson = {
  person_id: 1,
  name: 'Ole',
  age: 40,
  address: myAddress
}
```

I want to use destructuring to map to another type where person_id is renamed to personId:

```
interface IRenamed {
  personId: number
  name: string
  age: number
  address: IAddress
}

const newObj: IRenamed = {
  personId: 1,
  name: 'Ole',
  age: 40,
  address: myAddress
}
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
export function mapContractTemplate(p: IEntityPerson): IRenamed {
  const renamed = {
    person_id: personId,
    ...rest
  } = p
  return renamed
}
```

How can I do this?

Also, notice that the 'address' property is a nested object. Is there a smart way to do this with destructuring and/or spreading?

Answer (score 4):

Destructuring an object already defines the destructured properties as fields scoped to that block, they can't be assigned as a group to another field.

You can do it like this:

```
export function mapContractTemplate(p: IEntityPerson): IRenamed {
    const { person_id, address, ...rest } = p;
    return {
        personId: person_id,
        address: { ...address },
        ...rest
    }
}
```

This wil also create a copy of the address field, but it won't create a deep copy of it. So, in case `address` contains more nested objects or arrays you would have to do the nested destructuring manually.

Comment: I have a JSON object that has all sorts of weird characters (symbols, spaces etc) in the keys. Can I somehow still use destructuring?

Comment: yes, you likely will have to access the properties with bracket notation though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simple copy all properties to the a new object and apply the specific differences like this:

```
export function mapContractTemplate(p: IEntityPerson): IRenamed {

  // create a new object and add the new property
  const renamed = {
    personId: p.person_id
  };

  // blind copy all properties
  for(var key in p) {
     renamed[key]=p[key];
  }

  // delete the unwanted 'old' property
  delete renamed.person_id;
  return renamed;
}
```

This code keeps the same instance of address. It wasn't clear to me if you needed cloning of this object as well.

Answer (score 0):

well there is no dircet way to do it with destructing in my knowlage.
what you can do is

```js
export function mapContractTemplate(p: IEntityPerson): IRenamed {
  const clone =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p)) // deep clone the object
  clone.personId = clone.person_id
  delete clone.person_id;
  return clone
}
```